# how to fix a bottom relative layout when soft keyboard comes?

Tags: android

When i write something on the edit text in my app ,the soft keyboard comes in along with a bottom relative layout..I want to fix the bottom relative layout position fixed.Any help will be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 21):

I'm guessing Padma Kumar meant `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` on your manifest activity tag.

Comment: tsk tsk, how did this get so many up votes? `adjustNothing` is not even an option - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Answer (score 1):

add this in your activity tag in manifest.xml file

```
android:softinputmode="adjustNothing"
```

Comment: I want fix only the bottom layout..At the same time all other View should be adjustable, in the sense that My edit text to be fully visible to the user..

Comment: i'm also looking for the same type of solution as @hacker

Answer (score 1):

Make a fake layout with any height value, then reference it:

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/rl_fake"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="320dp" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/rl_main_view"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   ...
</RelativeLayout>
...
<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/rl_problem"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_below="@+id/rl_fake" >
   ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Relative layout paste the following code

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_continue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/conti"
            android:padding="@dimen/_8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```